# Как поменять формат даты от JSON?

Tags: php, json

Доброго времени суток друзья. Я получил при парсинге вот такую дату: **/Date(1582983000000)/.** 
Я так понял, это JSON .NET JavaScriptSerializer. 
Как мне преобразовать её в читабельный вид типа: 29.02.2020 ?
Можно ли средствами PHP или как это сделать через JS ?

Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Вам нужно взять число без последних трёх цифр. Это будет timestamp. Далее `date('d.m.Y', 1582983000)`

Comment: @Sice60 Как верно заменил ArchDemon - указанная Вами дата - это `timestamp` с миллисекундами. Чтобы вывести необходимый Вам формат, Вы можете воспользоваться примером Выше.